# Angular 4 Observable and ionic 3 - works the first 2 times, and then saying is not a function

Tags: angular, ionic3, observable

I'm having a weird problem.

I have a page called feed with files: feed.ts and feed.module.ts

On feed.ts I have this function:

```
  likeImage(image){

    console.log("Right before subscribe");
    this.imageMng.likeImage(image).subscribe((data) => {
      image.likes_image = data.status;
      image.numberOfLikes = data.numberOfLikes;
    });
  }
```

Which is subscribing to image-management.ts

```
   likeImage(image): Observable<any> {
    let data = new URLSearchParams();
    data.append('image_id', image.id);
    data.append('access_token', this.userMng.getToken());

    return Observable.create(observer => {
      this.http.post(this.likeLocal, data).map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(
          data => {
            if (data.status == "restored" || data.status == "liked") {
              this.likeImage = data.status;
              observer.next({status: true, numberOfLikes: data.likes});
              //observer.complete();
            }
            if (data.status == "deleted") {
              observer.next({status: false, numberOfLikes: data.likes});
              //observer.complete();
            }
            observer.complete();
          },
          err => {
            console.log(err);
            observer.next(err);
            //observer.complete();

          }
        );

    });

  }
```

The view that is being loaded is: images.html

```
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
      <button ion-button [color]="image.likes_image ? 'danger' : 'primary'" clear small icon-start (click)="likeImage(image);">
        <ion-icon name='thumbs-up'></ion-icon>
        <span *ngIf="image.numberOfLikes;then image_likes_from_likes_update else image_likes_from_server"></span> Synes godt om
        <ng-template #image_likes_from_likes_update>{{image.numberOfLikes}}</ng-template>
        <ng-template #image_likes_from_server>{{image.likes.length}}</ng-template>
      </button>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      <button ion-button color="primary" clear small icon-start>
        <ion-icon name='chatbubbles'></ion-icon>
        {{image.comments.length}} Kommentarer
      </button>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col center text-center>
      <ion-note>
        {{image.created_at | amTimeAgo}}
      </ion-note>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
```

When I click on "likeImage(image)" - it works, and makes a POST request to the server, and updates everything as expected.

If I do it again, it still works - BUT if I do it the third time, it gives me this error:

[image: this.imageMng.likeImage is not a function]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The issue looks like your function in the **image-management.ts**, your function `likeImage` shares its name with a variable? `this.likeImage = data.status;`. So at some point of time the function changes to status

Comment: Doesnt your IDE/linter throw an error for this?

Comment: I'm using WebStorm and that didn't complain at all.

But you were right, and everything works now!! - Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED!

In the file image-management.ts, function likeImage(image: Observable) I had this.likeImage = data.status, which will override likeImage.

The fix: image-management.ts

```
   likeImage(image): Observable<any> {
    let data = new URLSearchParams();
    data.append('image_id', image.id);
    data.append('access_token', this.userMng.getToken());

    return Observable.create(observer => {
      this.http.post(this.likeLocal, data).map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(
          data => {
            if (data.status == "restored" || data.status == "liked") {
              //this.likeImage = data.status;
              observer.next({status: true, numberOfLikes: data.likes});
              //observer.complete();
            }
            if (data.status == "deleted") {
              observer.next({status: false, numberOfLikes: data.likes});
              //observer.complete();
            }
            observer.complete();
          },
          err => {
            console.log(err);
            observer.next(err);
            //observer.complete();

          }
        );

    });

  }
```

Thanks to Suraj Rao!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when call a 'this' function inside class method when using 'promises' (not on ionic).

'this' is always the object of the method is called on. If you want to preserve 'this':

```
var that = this;
```

So you could write:

```
likeImage(image): Observable<any> {
    let data = new URLSearchParams();
    data.append('image_id', image.id);
    data.append('access_token', this.userMng.getToken());

    // preserve this
    let that = this;

    return Observable.create(observer => {
      that.http.post(that.likeLocal, data).map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(
          data => {
            if (data.status == "restored" || data.status == "liked") {
              that.likeImage = data.status;
              observer.next({status: true, numberOfLikes: data.likes});
              //observer.complete();
            }
            if (data.status == "deleted") {
              observer.next({status: false, numberOfLikes: data.likes});
              //observer.complete();
            }
            observer.complete();
          },
          err => {
            console.log(err);
            observer.next(err);
            //observer.complete();

          }
        );

    });

  }
```

Let me know.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work.
I tried what you wrote, and also to have a "let that = this" in the feed.ts.

But none of the above worked.